# Email Context analysis

Tags: email, email-spec

Hy, I am trying to analyze some email exchanges. Some mail servers integrate data context  into their email but I can't find this Intel into some others.

I want to find a way to check which email replies to which other or which email forward which other to create a graph of this exchanges.

On GMAIL emails they use the "In-Reply-To" and "References" tags; I've checked into other providers but I can't find these indicators. I find ARC-Message-Signature OR ARC-SEAL with some datas but it's not clear if they cary some data.

Aren't there any standards, or way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried exploring RFC documents for that?

Comment: I've tried, but only some provider tell which RFC they use. Like I said, some of them are explicit, but some other not. In case of ARC-Message-Signature I've got a ":message-id:to:from:date;" string  but it doesn't refer to the current mail Id. Or it's crypted...